# problems plotting int in x-axis with ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I want to get a simply plot using ggplot2 package. 
My dataframe has this structure

```
str(nrmse21)
'data.frame':   30 obs. of  3 variables:
$ Missing.rate: int  5 5 5 5 5 10 10 10 10 10 ...
$ Dataset     : Factor w/ 5 levels "hd","ir","mi",..: 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 ...
$ NRMSE       : num  0.00643 0.00696 0.00716 0.00442 0.00533 ...
```

I try to construct my plot with as follows:

```
ggplot(data = nrmse21, aes(x= Missing.rate, y = NRMSE, colour = Dataset, shape =Dataset))
```

But no points are shown, the only thing I see is the background with the x label `Missing.rate`and y label `NRMSE`
Whatam I doing wrong? how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the layer `geom_point` to your plot:

```
ggplot(data = nrmse21, aes(x= Missing.rate, y = NRMSE)) +  
    geom_point(aes(colour = DataSet,
                   shape = DataSet))
```

I recomend you to save this Cheat Sheet: https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ggplot2-cheatsheet.pdf